# Dummy Connection String Stopped Working When the Azure Web App was Migrated to .Net 6

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6, .net-6.0, azure-appservice

We have a Web Api 2 application that is using **.Net Framework 4.6.1**. Since we don't want our connection string to be exposed, the app has a dummy connection string in web.config when deployed to **Azure App Service**. [image]

That dummy connection string is being overridden by the connection string in Azure App Service Configuration. See this article: https://mohitgoyal.co/2017/07/05/update-connection-string-for-entity-framework-in-azure-web-app-settings/

It stopped working when we migrated to Asp.Net Core using **.Net 6**.
I have tried moving it to **app.config** but it still doesn't work.

We are still using Entity Framework 6 on .Net 6 and the connection string is being referenced in the constructor.

```
    public AppDBContext() : base("name=AppDBContext")
    {
    }
```

This is why we need to have our connection string in a config xml file rather than in the appsettings.json.

My questions are:

- Shouldn't azure app service treat app.config the same way it treats web.config?
- Should we change the way we reference the connection string so that we can read from the Azure AppService Configuration?

Comment: What is `app.config` ? Can you share us which article mentioned this, and I just know we can use `appsettings.json` file in asp.net core application.

Comment: Make sure your Connection String name in `Azure App settings` is same as in `appsettings.json` file.

Comment: Could you please share your `appsettings.json` and Azure App settings which you have tried ?

Comment: `app.config` is available in Console and Windows applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we create `Asp. Net Core` Web App using **.Net 6**, `appsettings.json` file will be created.

Add your Connection String in `appsettings.json`

***My appsettings.json***

```cs
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Your Connection String"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

[image]

***My Program.cs***

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
string connString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
```

> Shouldn't azure app service treat app.config the same way it treats web.config?

`app.config` is available in Console and Windows applications, whereas .NET Core Applications will have `appsettings.json` file to store connection strings and other Environment Variables.

The setting in `appsettings.json` will be overrided by Environment variables added in Azure App Settings .

Make sure your Connection String name in `Azure App settings` is same as in `appsettings.json` file.

***Connection String in Azure App Settings***
[image]